# awesome-typescript-loader Fail to load ts files

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

It was all good before my fellow clone the project and run npm install, npm start command. So I cleaned my node_modules to reproduce the issue in my env, then both of us stuck here. Any suggestion that what we can do?

tsc -v 2.1.1

error log:

> ```
> ERROR in ./src/polyfills.browser.ts Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'exclude' of undefined
> at applyDefaults (/Users/georgelin/Desktop/workspace/myApp/Jelly-Node/client/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/src/instance.ts:266:72)
> at Object.ensureInstance (/Users/georgelin/Desktop/workspace/myApp/Jelly-Node/client/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/src/instance.ts:145:5)
> at compiler (/Users/georgelin/Desktop/workspace/myApp/Jelly-Node/client/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/src/index.ts:37:20)
> at Object.loader (/Users/georgelin/Desktop/workspace/myApp/Jelly-Node/client/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/src/index.ts:18:18)
> ```
>
> @ multi polyfills

my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "@baumi/angular2-select": "^2.2.1",
    "angular-2-local-storage": "0.0.18",
    "angular2-fontawesome": "^0.5.1",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.3.0",
    "d3-brush": "^1.0.3",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "ng2-jsoneditor": "^0.1.0",
    "ng2-resource-rest": "^1.5.1",
    "ng2-select": "^1.1.2",
    "ng2-translate": "^3.1.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-events": "^3.1.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^3.4.34",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/d3": "^3.5.36",
    "@types/d3-brush": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-drag": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-selection": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/d3-tip": "^3.5.2",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.34",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.37",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/protractor": "^1.5.20",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.44.29",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.1.27",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.34",
    "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.4",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "codelyzer": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "es6-promise-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "^1.6.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.6.0",
    "parse5": "^2.2.2",
    "protractor": "^4.0.9",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^1.3.0",
    "tslint": "^4.0.0-dev.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "typings": "^0.7.12",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.1.0-beta.9",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "@types/isomorphic-fetch": "0.0.30",
    "typed-graphql": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^1.0.1"
  },
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "paths": {
    },
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "types": [
      "lodash",
      "d3"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "src/custom-typings.d.ts",
    "typings/browser.d.ts"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "resolveGlobs": true,
    "forkChecker": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: using version 2.0.10 solves the issue any version starting 2.1.x have the issue https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/190

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript 2.1 has breaking changes that don't currently work with Angular.

Change your version of Typescript from ^2.0.3 to ~2.0.3, delete your node_modules, and try again?

Comment: I changed my package.json file but there is a same error ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue and changing the version of typescript alone didn't work for me. Preceding steps helped me.

1. Run **"npm cache clean"** if npm version is below 5, or run **"npm cache verify"**
2. Go to your package.json
3. Change the version of **"awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4"** to **"awesome-typescript-loader": "2.2.4"**
4. Change the version of typescript **"typescript": "^2.0.3"** to **"typescript": "2.0.3"**
5. Run **"npm install"**

Now run **"npm run build"** if you have configured build, or run **"npm start"**, I am sure you will not get the error again.